# Class object is deleted after exiting the constructor or function

Tags: c++, qt, class

I have a Qt class MyPainter and 3 figures classes inhereted with AbstractFigure class.
In MainWindow.cpp I create 3 objects and add them into vector.

```
    Rectangle *rect = new Rectangle;
    Circle *circle = new Circle;
    Triangle *trial = new Triangle;


    std::vector<AbstractFigure *> prt_figures = {rect, circle, trial};
```

Then I have to send this vector to MyPainter class for the next useage.

In MyPainter.h I have another `std::vector<AbstractFigure *> ptr_figures;` where I wanna storage my data from MainWindow vector.
Tried to create another constructor

```
MyPainter::MyPainter(std::vector<AbstractFigure *> _ptr_figures)
{
    this->ptr_figures = _ptr_figures;

}
```

But as soon as programm leaves it `ptr_figures` becomes empty, it just gets deleted.

Special function doesn't help as well. `ptr_figures` maintains empty

```
std::vector<AbstractFigure *> MyPainter::GetVector(std::vector<AbstractFigure *> _ptr_figures)
{
    this->ptr_figures = _ptr_figures;
    return ptr_figures;
}
```

Because of that I cant draw my figures with

```
void MyPainter::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    for(auto items: this->ptr_figures)
    {
        absFigure(*items);
    }
}
```

Comment: `std::vector<AbstractFigure *> prt_figures = {rect, circle, trial};` looks like you are creating a local variable. I suspect the vector you pass to `MyPainter` constructor is not the same vector where you've added the three elements; that `_ptr_figures` parameter is in fact empty. For further assistance, show a [mcve]

Comment: Why does `GetVector` take an argument and change the `MyPainter` instance it's called on?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik When I start debugging and check the value of this vector that came from MainWindow it shows that it contains 3 values

Comment: Seconding @NathanPierson; `GetVector` doesn't make sense and looks suspicious. You are probably erasing `this->ptr_figures` there. Or the problem is elsewhere, in the code not shown. Again, prepare a [mcve]

Comment: @IgorTandetnik `GetVector` is just an expample. It doesn't work with it or without

Comment: For the third time: if you would like further assistance, show a [mcve].